# Android - Webview get page loading time

Tags: java, android, webview

Um I want to get the page loading time of a webview and check if it is equal to the timeout time but i dont know how to do it plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create subclass for `WebViewClient` and override `onPageLoadStarted` `onPageLoadFinished` methods. (Exact method names I don't remember.)

Attach subclass of `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`.

Write logic to find the time to load from page load start to page load finish.

```
`
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       long pageLoadStartTime;
       @Override
       public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
           pageLoadStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          long pageLoadTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - pageLoadStartTime;
      //pageLoadTime is you required data in milliseconds
       }
    });
`
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should use a `Timer` and listener on your `webview`

start timer as soon as the webview start loading your page , and stop it when it's done

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
    //start timer here
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // stop timer here
 }
});
```

Comment: Why a timer? Just get timestamp on start and timestamp on finish and do a simple substraction ?